# Is there a programmatic way to find out if my app has been rated?

Tags: android

In my android app, I want to display a dialog requesting the user to rate my app on the play store/market. This I want to do only if the user hadn't rated already. Please let me know if there is a way to do so.

Comment: You could skip the entire check and keep reminding them until they click some "stop reminding me"-button. Just saying...(I realize this would be somewhat annoying)

Comment: :) yeah, that is one way! But still, I would like to know if there is a way.

Comment: I can only answer it is possible, if you open Google Play and navigate app that you have already downloaded and rated, you can see the five blue stars shown here:) However, I don't know how Google Play do it, this specific app is not open source so impossible to take a shot in it:(

Answer (score 1):

No, You can't access the Market activity. Just you can check the review in Play.

Comment: But as far i remember, I could see some apps on App Store giving freebies like hints when the user rates their app. So is it specific to the apple API?

Comment: It's app/game specific, and I thought Google's changed the T&C's in the play store and incentives for reviews are not permitted.